# Unexpected output from program that brute-forces affine ciphers

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography

While writing a program to brute force affine ciphers, I stumbled upon some weird output.
For every a-value, the output seems to become overrun with a single letter as the b-value increases. It seems as if the result of the decryption equation can never go below -1 which it will need to in order for the program to work correctly but that is just a guess as to whats wrong.

```
a Value: 1

esxlnxxceslj
drwkmwwbdrki
cqvjlvvacqjh
bpuikuuzbpig
aothjttzaohf
znsgisszznge
zmrfhrrzzmfd
zlqegqqzzlec
zkpdfppzzkdb
zjoceoozzjca
zinbdnnzzibz
zhmacmmzzhaz
zglzbllzzgzz
zfkzakkzzfzz
zejzzjjzzezz
zdizziizzdzz
zchzzhhzzczz
zbgzzggzzbzz
zafzzffzzazz
zzezzeezzzzz
zzdzzddzzzzz
zzczzcczzzzz
zzbzzbbzzzzz
zzazzaazzzzz
zzzzzzzzzzzz
zzzzzzzzzzzz

a Value: 3

kgzvnzzskgvd
bxqmeqqjbxmu
sohdvhhasodl
jfyumyyrjfuc
awpldpprawlt
rngcuggrrnck
rextlxxrretb
rvokcoorrvks
rmfbtffrrmbj
rdwskwwrrdsa
runjbnnrrujr
rleaseerrlar
rcvrjvvrrcrr
rtmrammrrtrr
rkdrrddrrkrr
rburruurrbrr
rslrrllrrsrr
rjcrrccrrjrr
ratrrttrrarr
rrkrrkkrrrrr
rrbrrbbrrrrr
rrsrrssrrrrr
rrjrrjjrrrrr
rrarraarrrrr
rrrrrrrrrrrr
rrrrrrrrrrrr

a Value: 5
//and so on
```

In reality, only the first 5 or so lines for each a-value are correct. After that it seems to digress.

```
package Ciphers;

public class AffineBruteForce {
    private static String alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    
    public static void decrypt(String str) {
        str = str.toLowerCase();
        int[] aValues = {1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25};
        StringBuilder insert = new StringBuilder();
        
        //i = a-value
        for (int i = 0; i < aValues.length; i++) { 
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("a Value: " + aValues[i]);
            System.out.println();
            //j = b-value
            for (int j = 0; j < 25; j++) {      
        
                for (int k = 0; k < str.length(); k++) {
                    
                    //Decryption equation, x = a^-1(y–b) mod 26
                    int num = Math.floorMod(MultiInverse.modInverse(aValues[i], 26) * (alphabet.indexOf((str.charAt(k)) - j)), 26); 
                    insert.append(alphabet.charAt(num));            
                }
                System.out.println(insert.toString());
                insert.setLength(0);
            }
        }
    }
    
    public static void main (String[]args) {
        AffineBruteForce.decrypt("ESXLNXXCESLJ");
    }
}
```

```
package Ciphers;

public class MultiInverse {
    static int modInverse(int a, int m)
    {
      
        for (int x = 1; x < m; x++)
            if (Math.floorMod((Math.floorMod(a, m)) * (Math.floorMod(x, m)), m) == 1)
                return x;
        return 1;
    }
}
```

For example If we look at `a = 1`

Expected output

```
esxlnxxceslj
drwkmwwbdrki
cqvjlvvacqjh
bpuikuuzbpig
aothjttyaohf
znsgissxznge
ymrfhrrwymfd
xlqegqqvxlec
wkpdfppuwkdb
vjoceootvjca
uinbdnnsuibz
thmacmmrthay
sglzbllqsgzx
rfkyakkprfyw
qejxzjjoqexv
pdiwyiinpdwu
ochvxhhmocvt
nbguwgglnbus
maftvffkmatr
lzesueejlzsq
kydrtddikyrp
jxcqscchjxqo
iwbprbbgiwpn
hvaoqaafhvom
guznpzzegunl
ftymoyxdftmk
```

Actual Output

```
a Value: 1

esxlnxxceslj
drwkmwwbdrki
cqvjlvvacqjh
bpuikuuzbpig
aothjttzaohf
znsgisszznge
zmrfhrrzzmfd
zlqegqqzzlec
zkpdfppzzkdb
zjoceoozzjca
zinbdnnzzibz
zhmacmmzzhaz
zglzbllzzgzz
zfkzakkzzfzz
zejzzjjzzezz
zdizziizzdzz
zchzzhhzzczz
zbgzzggzzbzz
zafzzffzzazz
zzezzeezzzzz
zzdzzddzzzzz
zzczzcczzzzz
zzbzzbbzzzzz
zzazzaazzzzz
zzzzzzzzzzzz
zzzzzzzzzzzz
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like I was missing a pair of parenthesis in my decryption equation.

```
int num = Math.floorMod(MultiInverse.modInverse(aValues[i], 26) * (alphabet.indexOf((str.charAt(k)) - j)), 26);
```

Should have been

```
int num = Math.floorMod(MultiInverse.modInverse(aValues[i], 26) * (((alphabet.indexOf(str.charAt(k))) - j)), 26);
```